# Remove lines containing only 2-3 words starting with a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I need to remove lines having just 2-3 words starting with say 
hi/Hi/Hello/hello

*Example*

hi Matt

I have tried using the following code

```py
dropcols = ['Hi','hi','Hello']
dataextract = dataextract[~dataextract['text'].str.contains('|'.join(dropcols))]
```

But this would remove relevant lines like 
for example - 'hi Matt, did you get my email'

And I only need to remove the line if it has 
'hi Matt'

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
^(?=.*\b(?:hi|hello)\b).*$[\r?\n]
```

with `re.sub` might be an option.

```
import re

regex = r"^(?=.*\b(?:hi|hello)\b).*$[\r?\n]"

test_str = """
hi alice
some other words

Hi bob
some other words

Hello alice 
some other words

hello bob
some other words

hi Matt
some other words
"""

subst = ""

print(re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE | re.IGNORECASE))
```

#### Output

```
some other words

some other words

some other words

some other words

some other words
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/GYBuBr/1/) if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it.

Answer (score 0):

To match the first 2 or 3 words which start with hi/Hi/Hello/hello, you might use this pattern which you can remove from the string:

```
^[hH](?:i|ello)(?: \w+){1,2}
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `[hH]` Match h or H
- `(?:i|ello)` Match i or ello
- `(?: \w+){1,2}` Repeteat 1 - 2 times matching a space and 1+ word characters

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FX9vDt/1)

If you want to match all non whitespace characters, you could use `\S+` instead of `\w+`